# Testing Recurly.js locally

Tags: javascript, recurly

I am trying to test Recurly.js locally. When I call `recurly.configure("...my_public_key...)` I get an error.

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.recurly.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

Is there a way to set this up so I can test locally with out `https`? It seems like that would be in the settings or documentation somewhere but I can't find it.